# Read file with New Line in Python

Tags: python-3.7

Need help, i receive a file with new line.

```
name,age
"Maria",28
"Kevin",30
"Joseph",31
"Faith",20
"Arnel
",21
"Kate",40
```

How can I identify that line and remove it from the list?

output should be

```
name,age
"Maria",28
"Kevin",30
"Joseph",31
"Faith",20
"Kate",40
```

Comment: Which line do you want removed?

Comment: this line

"Arnel
",21

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach

```
import csv

data = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for line in reader:
        if not line[0].endswith("\n"):
            data.append(line)

with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

---

You can also correct the entry using `str.strip()`.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

data = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for line in reader:
        if line[0].endswith("\n"):
            line[0] = line[0].strip() 
        data.append(line)

with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: I tried this, but the output is still the same with the input